# Object push to bluetooth without pairing

Tags: bluetooth

Is it possible to send some notification messages to the nearby Bluetooth devices without pairing.I have found some protocol for these - OBEX Oject Push. But am not clear whether is is feasible without pairing request .Any demo apps for reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.
If you are actually talking about connecting but not pairing, then, yes.

If you are talking about no connection at all, then no.

When creating a Bluetooth connection between two or more devices the following steps are taken.

1. Inquiry – If two Bluetooth devices know absolutely nothing about each other, one must run an inquiry to try to discover the other. One device sends out the inquiry request, and any device listening for such a request will respond with its address, and possibly its name and other information. The closest located device is not necessarily the fastest to respond and any device that hears the call will try to respond.
2. Paging – Paging is the process of forming a connection between two Bluetooth devices. Before this connection can be initiated, each device needs to know the address of the other (found in the inquiry process).
3. Connection – After a device has completed the paging process, it enters the connection state. While connected, a device can either be actively participating or it can be put into a low power sleep mode.

   • Active Mode – This is the regular connected mode, where the device is actively transmitting or receiving data.

   •  Sniff Mode – This is a power-saving mode, where the device is less active. It’ll sleep and only listen for transmissions at a set interval (e.g. every 100ms).

   •  Hold Mode – Hold mode is a temporary, power-saving mode where a device sleeps for a defined period and then returns back to active mode when that interval has passed. The master can command a slave device to hold.

   •  Park Mode – Park is the deepest of sleep modes. A master can command a slave to “park”, and that slave will become inactive until the master tells it to wake back up.

Two devices can be bonded together through a one-time process called pairing. When two devices are paired, they store each other’s addresses, names and profiles in memory, allowing them to automatically establish a connection as soon as they are in range of each other.

It is not possible to send OPP (or other) communication between two devices before connecting.
It is possible to send communication between two devices after connection but before pairing.

Comment: Is connection event a request (i.e the client will send a request and peripheral should accept it )  ?  or it is automatically connected without any request ?

Comment: Usually this is a request that needs to be accepted.
In some devices you can turn this off, but that opens up a lot of security issues.

Comment: But for eg. proximity advertisements in shops push their advertisement to mobile phones as soon as the device is near. You mean those devices  too needs to accept the connection request by default ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible without a companion app in the phone that accepts the connection without notifying the end user.